# autocmd function always executed twice

Tags: vim, duplication, autocmd

I put together the following pile of awesomeness:

```
if !exists("g:AsciidocAutoSave")
  let g:AsciidocAutoSave = 0
endif

fun! AsciidocRefresh()
  if g:AsciidocAutoSave == 1
    execute 'write'
    execute 'silent !asciidoc -b html5 -a icons "%"'
  endif
endf

fun! AsciidocFocusLost()
  augroup asciidocFocusLost
    autocmd FocusLost <buffer> call AsciidocRefresh()
  augroup END
endfun

augroup asciidocFileType
  autocmd FileType asciidoc :call AsciidocFocusLost()
augroup END
```

The only problem is: It saves twice every time vim loses focus when in an `asciidoc` file.

When I put `:autocmd asciidocFileType` into the command line, it shows:

```
---Auto-Commands---
asciidocFileType  FileType
    asciidoc   :call AsciidocFocusLost()
               :call AsciidocFocusLost()
```

The same with `:autocmd asciidocFocusLost` and `AsciidocRefresh()`.

Why this duplication?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't tell you for sure *why* you got those duplicates (multiple sourcing?), but the canonical way to prevent this is clearing the `augroup` first:

```
augroup asciidocFileType
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType asciidoc :call AsciidocFocusLost()
augroup END
```

Since you only have one definition, you can also do this in one command:

```
augroup asciidocFileType
    autocmd! FileType asciidoc :call AsciidocFocusLost()
augroup END
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the trick with the `!` out in the meantime, making even the augroups unnecessary. But I guess I’m not the only one with a similar problem, so the question isn’t totally unnecessary.

Comment: With `!`, the augroups are important; otherwise, you may clear other, same event + pattern autocmds (from other plugins), too! The `:augroup` restricts the clearing to your own group.

Answer (score 0):

[@ingo-karkat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/813602/ingo-karkat)'s answer is great, but I think I know why you get twice as many `autocmd`s and how to prevent it naturally:

Some distributions of vim / Neovim make sure by default that `filetype plugin indent` is `on`. Test it for neovim with `env XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/dev/null nvim -c 'filetype'` or for vim with `env HOME=/dev/null vim -c filetype`

If the output is

```
filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON
```

Then You don't need to add `filetype * on` to your vimrc.